# Original Centos 6 version

Tags: centos, yum, command

Is there a command on Centos 6 that tells me which version was originally installed?

I have yum updated to 6.9. But is there a way to find what version was originally installed before any yum updates? eg 6.1, 6.2 etc

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no command that will directly provide that information.

You can indirectly find the initially installed release version by looking in `/var/log/anaconda/packaging.log`

```
grep -i centos-release packaging.log
```